# Magento Custom Order Attribute

Tags: magento

I am trying to add a custom attribute field to the `sales_flat_order` table in the database for Magento 1.8+.  Do I need to create a New Admin theme?

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: You need a setup script to add custom field to the database. If you are planning on may a lot of modification to the  admin template files than I recommend create an admin theme which limit then number of rewrite, custom layout.xml to rewrite template or editing core files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::ENTITY, 'THIS_IS_THE_CODE', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'default'       => '0',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'label'         => 'My pretty pretty label',
    'source'        => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'user_defined'  =>  false
));

$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::ENTITY, 'THIS_IS_THE_CODE', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'default'       => '0',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'label'         => 'My pretty pretty label',
    'source'        => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'user_defined'  =>  false
));
```